# Is there any performance effect when bind event to more svg elements in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am binding mousemove event to each svg element(path, circle,etc,.) to get individual  information for each elements (like tooltip ,obj info) . is it effect the performance ?

**JS:**

```
var elements = $(this.GroupEle).children();
for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) { //length may be 5000
    $(elements[j]).index = i;
    $(elements[j]).collection = objCollection;
    // performance issue ??????????????
    $(elements[j]).bind('mousemove', this.pointonChartMove);
}
```

I need to pass different data to handler for each element.

```
for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) { //length may be 5000
    //need to pass index and collection data to handler 
    $(elements[j]).index = i;
    $(elements[j]).collection = objCollection;
    $(elements[j]).bind('mousemove', this.pointonChartMove);
}
```

Pls suggest any other to achieve this????

Comment: Yes there is a performance hit - try attaching the handler to the parent element and let event bubbling help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of child elements you could see quite a performance hit. You could use a single delegated event handler on a parent element to help the situation:

```
$(this.GroupEle).on('mousemove', '.child-selector', this.pointonChartMove);
```

You would obviously need to change `.child-selector` to something relevant to your code.

Comment: May not even need the child selector come to think of it.

Comment: @ahren The children might not fill the parent. And this makes the context the right element.

Comment: @ahren you would, otherwise the event will be put on the parent, not the child element

Comment: Thanks for your updates. But, I cant solve my problem. Since, I need to pass different data to handler for each element.

for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) { //length may be 5000
    //need to pass index and collection data to handler 
    $(elements[j]).index = i;
    $(elements[j]).collection = objCollection;
    $(elements[j]).bind('mousemove', this.pointonChartMove);
}

Pls suggest any other to achieve this????